# JFrame is inactive during Thread.sleep(int)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, events, event-dispatch-thread

I have some Java classes that should simulate an old calculating machine. One of them is a JFrame, called **GUI**, with a **JTabbedPane**. The calculating process should take some time, so I have included **Thread.sleep(int)**. The problem is that while the calculating function is working, the tabs of the JTabbedPane in my GUI can't be selected.

Here is some code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Engine
{
    private GUI gui;
    private Store store;
    private Mill mill;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Engine e = new Engine();
    }

    public Engine() {
        gui = new GUI(this);
        mill = new Mill(this);
        store = new Store(this);

        store.draw();                       // affects GUI elements
    }

    public void read(String operations) {
        clearStatus();                      // affects GUI elements

        try {
            String[] op = operations.split("\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < op.length; i++) {
                setStatus(op[i]);        // affects GUI elements

                if (op[i].length() == 0) {  // empty line
                    continue;
                }

                int number = Integer.parseInt(op[i]);
                store.addNumber(number);

                Thread.sleep(200);
            }

            store.draw();                   // affects GUI elements

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void clearStatus() {
        gui.statusLabel.setText("");
    }

    public void setStatus(String msg) {
        gui.statusLabel.setText(msg);
    }
}
```

Here's my GUI (this is a short version):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame
{
    private Engine engine;

    // Swing
    JTabbedPane tabs;
    JPanel mill;
    JTextArea input, store;
    JLabel statusLabel;
    JButton sendInput;

    public GUI(Engine e)
    {
        engine = e;

        input = new JTextArea();
        sendInput = new JButton("Run");
        sendInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                pressInputButton(evt);
            }
        });

        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
        inputPanel.add(input,     BorderLayout.CENTER);
        inputPanel.add(sendInput, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mill = new JPanel();
        statusLabel = new JLabel();
        mill.add(statusLabel);

        store = new JTextArea();

        JTextPane helpPane = new JTextPane();
        helpPane.setText("[...]");

        tabs = new JTabbedPane();
        tabs.addTab("Input", inputPanel);
        tabs.addTab("Mill", mill);
        tabs.addTab("Store", new JScrollPane(store));
        tabs.addTab("Help", helpPanel);

        add(tabs, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }

    public void pressInputButton(ActionEvent evt) {
        engine.read(input.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: The terms `JFrame` and `Thread.sleep` should never be uttered ;)

Comment: Thread.sleep will lockup your entire thread, if you want your JFrame to continue to operate you need to do all your simulation code on another thread and only put that thread to sleep. Never sleep your JFrame thread.

Comment: That possible duplicate isn't exactly the same as your problem, but it's because of the same issue. Basically, when you do something on the Event Dispatch Thread which runs for a long time, the GUI itself isn't allowed to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What @sorifiend means is, calling `sleep()` from an *event handler* will "lock up" your application's *event dispatch thread*.  The application will not respond to any other user input until the event handler function returns.

If you want the application to be responsive while the calculator is "working", then what you need to do is:

- Record that the state of the calculator is "working"
- Disable whatever buttons you don't want the user to press while the calculator is "working", --OR-- change the handlers for those buttons to do something different (simulate jamming the machine?) if they are pressed while in the "working" state.
- Submit a timer event for some time in the near future (however long the calculation is supposed to take.)
- In the handler for the timer event, display the result of the calculation, re-enable the disabled buttons, and change the state from "working" back to "idle" (or whatever).

Comment: Properly more hassle than its worth, but another possible workaround rather than disable buttons is to overlay a single glasspane on top an area that the user should not interact with, then make it consume all user mouse events, this may be easier than disabling multiple components. (if you take this approach don't forget to consume key press events like the tab key that can bypass your glass pane)